# Connect Linqpad to Entity Framework without using Odata

Tags: entity-framework, odata, wcf-data-services, linqpad

I'm weak on my fundamentals here, so feel free to let me know if I'm making any bizarre/false assumptions: I'm working on a project with WCF data services and due to the limitations of Odata as a querying language (e.g. no select distinct, joins are difficult, etc.), we're going to expose some service operations for common & non-trivial queries.  So, I like using linqpad to get my linq code correct, and I'd like to use linqpad to target the entity framework directly (this is important: not through Odata).  Is there a way I can target EF directly?  Would it have to be on the same machine?  What is the process?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can target EF directly if you can point LINQPad to an assembly containing the typed ObjectContext that you created in Visual Studio. Click **Add Connection** and choose **Entity Framework** in the bottom listbox.